# fscanf specific digits from a file

Tags: c, file, scanf

So I got this file and i want to `scanf()` only the digits inside the first `{}` than the digits inside the second `{}` and so on.
I've managed to call just the digits from the file, but I don't know how to separate them into groups

this is the file:

```
{5, 2, 3}, {1,5}, { }, { }, {3}, { }, { }
```

Below is the code I use so far

```
    void main()
{
    int rc=0,num,size;
    FILE* f = fopen("graph-file.txt","rt");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open the file\n");
    }
    size = fscanf(f,"%d",&num);
    fseek(f,1,SEEK_CUR);
    while(rc != EOF)
    {
            if( rc == 1)
            {
                printf("%d\n",num);
            }
            fseek(f,1,SEEK_CUR);
        rc = fscanf(f,"%d",&num);

    }
}
```

Comment: How did you learn `fscanf()`? This code is wrong, for example there is no guarantee that `rc` will be `EOF` the first time `fscanf()` fails.

Comment: `if( ch =='{')` is testing an *uninitialised variable* that is not even subsequently set.

Comment: i put the whole code if it helps
@WeatherVane dont notice to this line i removed it

Comment: So you struggled so long over 20 lines of code that you didn't even notice a variable you don't use? BTW it should be `int main(void)`

Comment: Are you sure a JSON library wouldn't be a better choice?  Failing that, then it looks like 'read line; process line, not necessarily only with `sscanf()`' would be a sensible approach, to make skipping over `{` and `}` easier.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are probably what you're going to need to accomplish this task.  Arrays allow you to have various amounts of digits that you can store what you read into.  That's how you can separate the groupings.  The next part will be how to change which part of the array you're looking at, which this link should also help with.
[C Arrays Tutorial.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson8.html)

If the numbers that you're trying to read will only be single digit numbers, then you could ditch the fseek and fscanf functions and use getc instead.  Just check each read for anything that's not a number '0'-'9'.
[C getc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/)

Those websites I linked also have a lot of other good tutorials on them for learning C\C++.

Good luck.
Edit: less condescending.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is has some issues, for example the mode string is wrong `"rt"`? You only need to specify `"b"` for binary and that only affects the *end of line* character which can be a problem if the file is read/written on different platforms.

To achieve what you want there is no simple way, as @[JonathanLeffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) suggests [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798977/fsacnf-specific-digits-from-a-file#comment57342979_34798977) you could use a *json* library [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)<sup>1</sup> is a very easy to use one.

If you want to do it yourself, try this code that I did just write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
append_number(int size, int **arrays, int value)
{
    void *pointer;

    pointer = realloc(arrays[0], (++size + 1) * sizeof(**arrays));
    if (pointer == NULL)
        return 0;
    arrays[0] = pointer;
    arrays[0][size] = value;

    return 1;
}

int
get_value(const char *input)
{
    if (input == NULL)
        return -1;
    while ((*input != '\0') && (isspace((unsigned char) *input) != 0))
        input++;
    if (*input == '\0')
        return -1;
    return atoi(input);
}

int *
extract_arrays(char *array)
{
    int value;
    int *list;
    list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    if (list == NULL)
        return NULL;
    list[0] = 0;
    while (array != NULL)
    {
        char *delimiter;

        delimiter = strchr(array, ',');
        if (delimiter != NULL)
            *delimiter = '\0';
        value = get_value(array);
        if (value > 0)
            list[0] += append_number(list[0], &list, value);
        if (delimiter != NULL)
            array = delimiter + 1;
        else
            array = NULL;
    }

    return list;
}

void
print_array(int *list)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "[");
    for (int j = 1 ; j < list[0] ; ++j)
        fprintf(stdout, "%d ", list[j]);
    if (list[0] > 0)
        fprintf(stdout, "%d", list[list[0]]);
    fprintf(stdout, "]\n");
}

int **
parse_line(char *line, size_t *count)
{
    char *open;
    char *close;
    char *next;
    int **arrays; // Depends on the maximum size of an inner array

    *count = 0;
    arrays = NULL;
    next = line;

    while ((next != NULL) && ((open = strchr(next, '{')) != NULL))
    {
        close = strchr(open, '}');
        if (close != NULL)
        {
            void *pointer;
            char *values;

            *close = '\0';
            next = strchr(close + 1, ',');
            values = open + 1;
            pointer = realloc(arrays, (*count + 1) * sizeof(*arrays));
            if (pointer == NULL)
                goto error;
            arrays = pointer;

            arrays[(*count)++] = extract_arrays(values);
        }
        else
            next = open + 1;
    }
    return arrays;
error:
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < *count ; ++i)
        free(arrays[i]);
    free(arrays);
    *count = 0;
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[100];
    size_t count;
    int **arrays;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("graph-file.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return -1; // Failure openning the file
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
    {
        arrays = parse_line(line, &count);
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
        {
            print_array(arrays[i]);
            // DO something with it ...
            free(arrays[i]);
        }
        free(arrays);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, there are a lot of possible optimizations (*specially the `realloc()` parts*), but I leave that to you.

Above, the `int **` pointer returned by `parse_line()` contains `count` arrays where the first element is the length of each array.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I know that on most linux distributions it can be installed with the package manager, and I have been using it a lot recently for some web development related projects.</sub>